# URL redirected to subdirectory Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a www root document which contains some subdirectories, where I want to route my requests conditionally to the domain requested.

For example. If the domain requested is *testsite.com* the Apache server should run the contents of the subfolder */testsite.com*. If the domain requested is *testiste.org* Apache should run the */testsite.org* folder.

Actually my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oliotarcento\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oliotarcento.com/$1 [L]
```

In that case the rule works fine but not at all.
This is a curious case:

http://www.oliotarcento.com/forum/ works fine, but if I omit the trailing slash like http://www.oliotarcento.com/forum my browser will be redirected to http://www.oliotarcento.com/oliotarcento.com/forum/.

What I'm wrong?

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `forum` is a directory and `mod_dir` adda a trailing slash to redirected URL. Try this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oliotarcento.com/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oliotarcento\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!oliotarcento\.com/).*)$ oliotarcento.com/$1 [L,NC]
```